# read properties with '=' and white spaces from app.properties in unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, properties

I'm reading the properties as shown below, but because I'm using the = sign, it's breaking. How can I read the full property?
In property file
`dbName=jdbc://sample:8080;nameSpace=name1; --config host=sample`

```
# Script used to read Property File
FILE_NAME=Test.prop
# Key in Property File
key="dbName"

# Variable to hold the Property Value
prop_value=""

getProperty()
{
        prop_key=$1
        prop_value=`cat ${FILE_NAME} | grep ${prop_key} | cut -d'=' -f2`
}

getProperty ${key}
echo "Key = ${key} ; Value = " ${prop_value}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove all text up to the first `=`.

```sh
prop_value=$(grep "^${prop_key}=" ${FILE_NAME} | sed 's/[^=]*=//')
```

Notes:
You rarely need `cat` for the input files. I modified the `grep` pattern to match the complete key at the beginning of the line only. This avoids matches for lines that may contain the specified key as a substring of the key or value. I replaced the backticks with `$(...)`.